# My For loop returns the wrong expected outcome

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, math

My code:

```
#Program to calculate statistics from student test scores.
midterm_scores = [99.5, 78.25, 76, 58.5, 100, 87.5, 91, 68, 100]
final_scores = [55, 62, 100, 98.75, 80, 76.5, 85.25]

#Combine the scores into a single list
all_scores = midterm_scores + final_scores

num_midterm_scores = len(midterm_scores)
num_final_scores = len(final_scores)

print(num_midterm_scores, 'students took the midterm.')
print(num_final_scores, 'students took the final.')

#Calculate the number of students that took the midterm but not the final
dropped_students = num_midterm_scores - num_final_scores
print(dropped_students, 'students must have dropped the class.')

lowest_final = min(final_scores)
highest_final = max(final_scores)

print('\nFinal scores ranged from', lowest_final, 'to', highest_final)

# Calculate the average midterm and final scores
# Hint: Sum the midterm scores and divide by number of midterm takers
#       Repeat for the final
average_midterm = 0
for i in range(len(midterm_scores)):
    average_midterm += average_midterm + i

average_midterm = average_midterm / len(midterm_scores)
print('The average midterm score for the class is:', average_midterm)

average_final = 0
for x in range(len(final_scores)):
    average_final += average_final + x
    
average_final = average_final / len(final_scores)
print('The average final score for this class is:', average_final)
```

Unless my math is just actually this bad, why are my average test scores coming out totally wrong? Is my For loop or arguments wrong or is my math wrong?

Please excuse my novice question, thank you.

Comment: Why do you think they are wrong?

Comment: My outcome is coming out totally wrong, unless my interpreter is just bugged or something.

Comment: In the `For` loop, this part `average_midterm += average_midterm + i`  just adds each **index** ( e.g `0`,`1`,`2`, and so on), not the actual string index, e.g. `midterm_scores[2]` or something.

Comment: Your summing loops use this expression to accumulate the running total: `average_final += average_final + x`.  should just be `average_final += x` . Converting to using builtin `sum()` will also fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Python's built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function instead.

```
average_midterm = sum(midterm_scores) / len(midterm_scores)
```

Comment: welp... that was easy lol. Thanks so much, I guess this is part of the learning.

Comment: Although using `sum` is the preferred approach, I think it's worth explaining how to fix the for-loop in the OP's code.